# rake db:create gives NoMethodError: undefined method `init' for Rails:Module

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

mysql seems to be working - i can

```
$ mysql -uroot
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 5.6.27 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
mysql>
```

However in a rails project we've used ok for a while:

```
$ rake db:create
14:47:41 mdurrant EQ-267 /Users/mdurrant/eq/lynx master
$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `init' for Rails:Module
/Users/mdurrant/eq/lynx/config/initializers/configatron.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/application.rb:305:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
...
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
14:50:33 mdurrant EQ-267 /Users/mdurrant/eq/lynx master
$

$ cat config/initializers/configatron.rb 
require 'configatron'
Configatron::Rails.init
```

Comment: What code is in `configatron.rb`?

Comment: Added that info to the question

Comment: Are you sure you have an `init` method defined at _module_ level in `Configatron::Rails`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to temporarily remove the configatron.rb file and see if that helps. The error is at line 2 so this is where the problem lies.

Hard to be sure without seeing the file but I'd try this to permanently fix it:

1. add `require 'configatron'` to app.rb
2. change the line so it says `Configatron::Integrations::Rails.init` instead of `Configatron::Rails.init`.